# Google Script Formula Callback Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not really sure whats off on my script. My first script is event based and moves data from the main tab to the CSV tab which is essentially a staging table for the 2nd and 3rd function that creates a .csv file into my google drive. Both `onEdit(event)` and `saveAsCSV()` funtion properly on their own, but I really want to nest `saveAsCSV()` into my `onEdit(event)` function so that a csv. file is saves at the same time as the staging table is created. Any Idea's why the script bellow isnt working? Also I'm a little concerened with the timing of the the functions running since I need the `onEdit(event)` portion to finish creating the staging table before it creates the csv. file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var loopLengthNumber = r.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i < loopLengthNumber.length; i++) { 
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSV");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  s.insertRowsAfter(s.getLastRow(), loopLengthNumber.length);
  saveAsCSV();
}

function saveAsCSV() {
    var daTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    var fileName = "Tasting7 Room "+ daTime;
    if (fileName.length !== 0) {
      fileName = fileName + ".csv";
      var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
      DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile, MimeType.CSV);
  }


  function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CSV").getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you physically pasting data into a range? Which sheet?

Comment: @Cooper in a sense yes. I have a link from my Shopify account that drops orders into the "main" tab. But for this exercises I have been pasting in data on "main" which transfers over to "CSV".

Comment: It's not going to work when a user is not pasting the data in.  So my guess is that your wasting your time.  onEdit() only triggers for USER edits.

Comment: @Cooper is that because of the data coming from the Shopify integration onto "main" tab, or because the function moves the data over to the "CSV" tab?

Comment: onEdit only trigger on user edits.   When a use has a user interface opened up and they make a physical edit that's the only time that the trigger will fire. Also if your using an installable onedit then you should change the name otherwise you could be getting multiple triggers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Answer for question 1:

> Any Idea's why the script bellow isnt working?

If `isnt working` is the CSV file is not created, I think that in your script, it is required to use the installable trigger for using the method of `createFile()`. So please rename the function name of `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit` as a sample, and [install the function as the installable OnEdit event trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

#### Answer for question 2:

> Also I'm a little concerened with the timing of the the functions running since I need the `onEdit(event)` portion to finish creating the staging table before it creates the csv.

In the current stage, the Google Apps Script runs with the synchronous process. So in your case, the script works before `saveAsCSV()` is run.

I think that in your situation, the result is the same with and without using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike that is what I'm trying to do. Did you see @Cooper note above your answer? He said that because its a drop from a shopify connection into "main" and then a function that moves the data onto the "CSV" tab that this wont work? Also I dont totally understand the installable triggers vs the on edit function. Sorry i'm still pretty green to all of this. Any help is very  much appreciated.

Comment: @Ricky Adams Thank you for replying. From your replying, it seems that about `isnt working` in your question, there are several issues. In order to use `createFile()` using OnEdit event trigger, it is required to use the installable OnEdit event trigger. If the simple trigger `onEdit` is used, when `createFile()` is run, an error occurs related to the authorization. And in order to correctly understand about `isnt working`, can I ask you about the detail of it?